# WYSIWYG LaTeX editor that can export high-resolution images

Tags: editors, resolution

I am looking for a (La)TeX editor – either **web-based** or **OS X** – that meets these criteria for mathematical notation:

- Can export high-resolution images (e.g. 1000+ dpi, adequate for a MBP Retina screen).
- WYSIWYG interface, preferably instantaneous. I am a TeX newbie and would like to be able to select notation from a menu and get instant graphic feedback on the screen.

I keep my formulas in Evernote. I have previously used [MathType](http://www.dessci.com/en/products/mathtype/), but the two don't work that well together. I won't go in on the details why; but basically you either have to choose between big high resolution images that aren't sufficiently resizable, or adequately-sized images with low resolution.

I have searched around the web but haven't found any online editors that meet these criteria, yet.

Comment: Often asked, always got the answer: Doesn't exist. Some applications try to do it, but fail at some point or another.

Comment: “I am a TeX newbie and would like to be able to select formula from a menu and get instant graphic feedback on the screen.” At least try just a basic editor, I think you can adapt easily (less than 5 hours writing math in TeX) and you will probable be much faster after some time. Just try it.

Comment: [This could be related.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Okay, skipping WYSIWYG and using only plain text, are there any advisable applications or services that can easily can output high-resolution images?

Comment: You don't need to export anything. You just compile to PDF and this is vector, hence scalable. It doesn't matter which editor you use - the underlying compilation process is the same.

Comment: @cfr True, but unfortunately Evernote doesn't support scaling PDFs. This sad fact is the raison d'être for my question, hence the need to export high-resolution images.

Comment: Maybe take a look at `standalone`. TikZ, MetaPost etc. can export images but you aren't drawing diagrams, I think. `standalone` can work with anything. There are also tailored programmes for doing this, like LaTeXIt (? maybe mangling name) but those are often OS-specific. If I'm remembering the name correctly, that's an OS X application. (But I've not used OS X for ages so I may be misremembering or it may no longer exist.)

Comment: I don't quite understand this question (because I don't have a good understanding of Retina screens). If you are looking for a GUI for LaTeX, consider using LyX. LyX does work with MBP Retina screen, but it won't look completely smooth until the next version is released (a few months). Users say LyX is completely usable as is, but just pixelated. 2.2.0 should make things smoother.